# android onClickListener with a bug

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I am try to to implement onItemClickListener , attached is my code and xml files . To my understanding when i click any textview , i should return me the unique id ; but here it is returning just 0 . Not sure why , thanks in advance for the solutions .

my main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener   {
public static final String number = "number" ;
public static final String email ="email" ;
public static final String name ="name";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
for (int i=0 ;i <=5;i++){
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(number, i+"");
    map.put(email, i+"email");
    map.put(name,i+"name");

    userList.add(map);  
}
settextView(userList);
final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void settextView(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList) 
{
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, userList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] {number , email ,name  },
            new int[] { R.id.userName, R.id.ventDesc ,R.id.ventUserName});
    // updating listview
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String numberPressed = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName)).getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CLICK: " + numberPressed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Log.d("selected is ",numberPressed);

}
}
```

main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>
```

list xml :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/userName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     />
<!-- Name Label -->

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ventUserName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ventDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

PS: i did try to debug the code and honestly nothing seems to be helping me

Comment: What "unique id" do you expect it to return and why?

Comment: Maybe String numberPressed = ((TextView) _view_.findViewById(R.id.userName)).getText().toString();

Comment: @codeMagic i am trying to print "userName"

Comment: @Deucalion --> thanks it worked , i get the logic now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change String numberPressed = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName)).getText().toString();
to String numberPressed = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.userName)).getText().toString();